# Installing R kernel for Ipython on Windows

Tags: r, ipython, jupyter

I am on Windows 10. I have installed R-3.2.0, Anaconda 2.2.0 64 bit, RStudio-0.99.446. Also, edited system path variable to include R installation directory.

I am following all the instruction given in https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel but I am not getting R kernel when I open Ipython notebook.

Can anybody tell what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working, after following all the process mentioned in IRkernel GitHub page.
Create kernel.json file in C:\Users\[username]\.ipython\kernels\R_kernel, content of the file should be

```
{"argv": ["C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.0/bin/R.exe","-e","IRkernel::main()",
"--args","{connection_file}"],
"display_name":"R"
}
```

Note that instead of forward slash path should contain backward slash as mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks, I've found many suggestions on the Web, but this is the only one working in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Once `IRkernel` is installed, you can also simply issue the following command in R:

```
IRkernel::installspec(user = FALSE)
```

The `kernel.json` file should be automatically created in the appropriate folder ("C:\ProgramData\jupyter\kernels\ir"), along with a nice R logo

Answer (score 0):

Those who haven't installed it yet can follow these instructions:

Visit this [LinkedIn post](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/gu%C3%ADa-para-el-uso-de-r-con-anaconda-en-windows-ferdinando-feoli/) if you want to read the instructions in spanish.

**1) Create your R virtual enviroment**

Skip this step if you have it already. If you don't know how to create it, visit [this page](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/tutorials/create-r-environment/).

**2) Get your R executable path**

This step is to make sure you to use the proper instalation of R through the next steps and with that, avoid reference/path errors later. There are several ways to get the path, the one I propose is the following:

- 2.1 Run Anaconda prompt as administrator. If you don't know how to do it visit [this page](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/getting-started/#open-prompt).
- 2.2 In Anaconda Prompt, active your R virtual enviroment using the command `activate {my enviroment's name}`(notice that, in my case, I named my R virtual enviroment as 'RStudio'):

[image]

- 2.3 Run R: Just type R and press Enter.

[image]

- 2.4 Run the following method to get the base path.

`R.home()`

[image]

- 2.5 Navigate to the path you got in the previous step (you can use Windows Explorer for this), go to the *bin* folder and copy the path where R.exe is located.
  **Notice:** If your OS have a 64bit architecture, you should copy the path from the *x64* folder.

In my case:

[image]

**3) Quit R session, and then, deactivate your virtual enviroment**

You can use the method `q()` to quit R. For deactivating your virtual enviroment use the command: `conda deactivate`

[image]

**4) Run R from your base enviroment**

Go to the path you copied in *Step 2*. For that, use the command:

```
cd {your path here}
```

Once there, type R.exe and press Enter.

e.g.

[image]

If you got no errors here, go to **Step 5**.

If you got a dynamic link library error like this when trying to run R.exe:

[image]

Use the following command:

```
conda install -c r r
```

[image]

Once solved, run R.exe again and then, continue to **Step 5**

**5) Installing R kernel stuff**

Now, you're in Anaconda Prompt as Administrator, with your R session opened from the base enviroment, the next you must do is:

- 5.1 Install **devtools**. Just run the following method with "devtools" as parameter:

`install.packages("devtools")`

- 5.2 Install **RTools**. Follow the steps [explained here](http://jtleek.com/modules/01_DataScientistToolbox/02_10_rtools/#1).
- 5.3 Install **IRkernel**. Follow the steps [explained here](https://irkernel.github.io/installation/).

Now, your R kernel is set and ready to go!

[image]